# Linear Solve with Modular Arithmetic

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, options, modular-arithmetic

I am interested in using `LinearSolve[m,b]` which will find a solution to the equation $m.x=b$, where I am in mod 2 arithmetic. Is there any way to perform this computation in *Mathematica* ?

Comment: You know that `LinearSolve[]` takes a `Modulus` option, no?

Comment: @J.M., I did not know that. Can you tell me how I would do this syntactically?

Comment: Did you look at [the docs for `LinearSolve[]`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/LinearSolve.html#222012567)?

Comment: @Artes Sorry that I forgot to accept your answer, yes it was helpful and exactly what I needed to finish writing my Algorithm. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an option `Modulus` in certain algebraic functions (`Solve`, `LinearSolve`, `Det`,`Factor` etc.) to specify that integers are to be treated modulo an integer n. Consider e.g.

```
m0 = {{4, 6, 6}, {6, 3, 2}, {1, 4, 4}};
b0 = {4, 2, 1};
```

then

```
LinearSolve[ m0, b0, Modulus -> 2]
```

> ```
>  {1, 0, 0}
> ```

You can work with `LinearSolve` specifying only the first variable, then it generates a linear operator, e.g. let :

```
m1 = {{1, 0, 1, 5}, {0, 4, 6, 7}, {0, 2, 3, 1}, {1, 7, 0, 8}};
c1 = LinearSolve[m1, Modulus -> 2]
```

> ```
> LinearSolveFunction[{4,4},<>]
> ```

`c1`  yields automatically solutions modulo `2`. It can be convenient to work with `Manipulate` :

```
Manipulate[  c1[{a1, a2, a3, a4}],
            {a1, -5, 5, 1}, {a2, -5, 5, 1}, {a3, -5, 5, 1}, {a4, -5, 5, 1}]
```

[image]