# Solving a system of linear equations modulo n

Tags: equation-solving, linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have a system of linear equations

$$ a+b+c \equiv  31  \pmod{54}  $$
$$ 4a+2b+c \equiv  3  \pmod{54}  $$
$$ 9a+3b+c \equiv  11  \pmod{54}  $$

What should I input (I'm using `LinearSolve`)? It doesn't seem to work for composite modulo numbers. I have been unable to get *Mathematica* to give me all the possible solutions.

Comment: Something like this: `Solve[{Mod[a + b + c, 54] == 31, Mod[4 a + 2 b + c, 54] == 3, Mod[9 a + 3 b + c, 54] == 11}, {a, b, c}, Integers]`?

Comment: Perhaps: `Reduce[{a + b + c == 31, 4 a + 2 b + c == 3, 9 a + 3 b + c == 11}, {a, b, c}, 
 Modulus -> 54]` ?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Great. It works and gives all the solutions. Do you know a good tutorial for solving equations, inequalities, modular problems for Mathematica?

Comment: There is a huge list of general resources [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/18/121).  I can't think of anything specific at the moment.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate: [(11580)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/11580/121)

Comment: Yeah I googled and found only LinearSolve and even that wasn't working.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard It's related but not a duplicate, the user points out unreliability of `LinearSolve` ( I guess with `Modulus`).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Working with `LinearSolve` we encounter some inconsistency of the related option 
`Modulus -> z` if `z` is not prime. Nonetheless we could do this

```
Mod[ LinearSolve[ {{1, 1, 1}, {4, 2, 1}, {9, 3, 1}}, {31, 3, 11}], 54]
```

> ```
> {18, 26, 41}
> ```

Unfortunately we can get only one solution unlike when working with `Solve`. 
These posts describe another problems or bugs related to `Modulus` or `Mod`:

[Solving/Reducing equations in Z/pZ](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/16001/solving-reducing-equations-in-mathbbz-p-mathbbz/16003#16003)
[Strange behaviour of Reduce for Mod[x,1]](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/9531/strange-behaviour-of-reduce-for-modx-1)

Note that the latter points some bugs present in versions `7` and `8` which have been fixed in version `9` of *Mathematica*.

Even though `LinearSolve` doesn't appear to be an appropriate approach w can use the `Modulus` option in another equation-solving functionality like e.g.: `Solve` or `Reduce` and in some other functions related to algebraic manipulations.
This yields a symbolic result:

```
Solve[{  a + b + c   == 31, 
       4 a + 2 b + c ==  3,
       9 a + 3 b + c == 11}, {a, b, c}, Modulus -> 54]
```

> ```
> {{a -> 18 + 27 C[1], b -> 26 + 27 C[1], c -> 41}}
> ```

To get a full list of solutions we should put the result in a table, (changing generated parameters since they are protected to another ones e.g. `k`). We can see that we need the table of length two only otherwise we would get may duplicates.

```
Table[ Mod[{a, b, c} /. %, 54] /. C[1] -> k, {k, 2}]
```

> ```
> {{{45, 53, 41}}, {{18, 26, 41}}}
> ```

These are all solutions of the related system $\mod 54$:

```
Apply[{ Mod[#1 + #2 + #3, 54] - 31, 
        Mod[4 #1 + 2 #2 + #3, 54] - 3, 
        Mod[9 #1 + 3 #2 + #3, 54] - 11}&, %, {2}]
```

> ```
>   {{{0, 0, 0}}, {{0, 0, 0}}}
> ```