# Non-valid modulus when using LinearSolve

Tags: linear-algebra, modular-arithmetic

I have a system of linear equations I want to solve mod 4, and I happen to know the solution, but I get an error when trying to solve it using LinearSolve. I define the matrix `M` on line 31, define my known solution, `b` on line 32, and verify it on line 33. But trying to solve it using LinearSolve I get the error `Matrix is not valid modulo 4`. Here's the print of my inputs and outputs:

[image: Here's a print of the inputs and the error I get].

Edit:

Here's the matrix in question

```
M := {{1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0},
{1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0},
{1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1},
{1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0},
{0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0},
{0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1},
{1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1},
{0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1},
{0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1}}
```

and the solution

`b := {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2}`.

Comment: Please paste in your code to the question, not a screenshot, as it's too tedious to type out.

Comment: Updated my post with the matrix in question.

Comment: `Det[M, Modulus -> 4]` is zero, but you can find solutions using `FindInstance[M.Array[x, 9] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, Array[x, 9], Modulus -> 4]` . I'm a little spooked that `LinearSolve` couldn't do it though.

Comment: Thank you. I'm on Mathematica 10.0 if that makes any difference.

Comment: From the docs: _Some functions require that Modulus be set to a prime, or a power of a prime. $\mathbb{Z}_n$ is a finite field when n is prime._ 4 is 2^2 but perhaps because `PowerMod[2, -1, 4] ... PowerMod::ninv: 2 is not invertible modulo 4.` you cannot use it here as 2 has no multiplicative inverse and integers mod 4 do not form a finite field. You may have to stick with `FindInstance` then.

Comment: Where the "usual" row reduction fails due to lack of multiplicative inverses, the function to consider using is `HermiteDecomposition`. That's what `Solve` will be using under the hood in this case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is caused by the integers mod 4 not forming a finite field and 2 having no unique multiplicative inverse. This prevents `RowReduce` from doing its job, even with `Method->"DivisionFreeRowReduction"`.

```
PowerMod[2, -1, 4]
(* PowerMod::ninv: 2 is not invertible modulo 4. *)
```

One possibility is to use `FindInstance`:

```
FindInstance[M.Array[x, 9] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, Array[x, 9], Modulus -> 4]
```

But better is `Solve` which works because it can generate a class of solutions with generated parameters unlike `LinearSolve`. Setting the generated parameters to zero yields the solution `b`.

```
Mod[Values[
  Solve[M.Array[x, 9] == {0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0}, Array[x, 9], 
    Modulus -> 4] /. C[_] :> 0
  ], 4]

(* {{0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 2}} *)
```

Other solutions appear with `C[_]:>1` or `C[_]:>3` (modulo 4):

```
{{2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2}}
```

... and many more are possible from the family:

```
fam = {2 C[1], 1 + 2 C[2], 2 C[3], 1 + 2 C[4], 2 C[1] + 2 C[2] + 2 C[4], 
 1 + 2 C[1] + 2 C[3] + 2 C[4], 2 + 2 C[1] + 2 C[2] + 2 C[3] + 2 C[4], 
 3 + 2 C[3] + 2 C[4], 2 + 2 C[2] + 2 C[4]};

rules = Thread[{C[1], C[2], C[3], C[4]} -> #] & /@ Tuples[{0, 1, 2, 3}, 4];
DeleteDuplicates[Mod[fam /. rules, 4]];

(*
{0,1,0,1,0,1,2,3,2}
{0,1,0,3,2,3,0,1,0}
{0,1,2,1,0,3,0,1,2}
{0,1,2,3,2,1,2,3,0}
{0,3,0,1,2,1,0,3,0}
{0,3,0,3,0,3,2,1,2}
{0,3,2,1,2,3,2,1,0}
{0,3,2,3,0,1,0,3,2}
{2,1,0,1,2,3,0,3,2}
{2,1,0,3,0,1,2,1,0}
{2,1,2,1,2,1,2,1,2}
{2,1,2,3,0,3,0,3,0}
{2,3,0,1,0,3,2,3,0}
{2,3,0,3,2,1,0,1,2}
{2,3,2,1,0,1,0,1,0}
{2,3,2,3,2,3,2,3,2}
*)
```

You may want to read [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/31704/72682) which goes into more detail.